# How can i get grouped data in Sub-Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have Table with below data

```
Id      date
-----------------------------------
1       2014-06-11 08:35:00.000
2       2014-06-11 08:35:00.000
3       2014-06-11 08:50:00.000
4       2014-06-11 08:55:00.000
5       2014-06-11 08:55:00.000
```

I want to query and group the row by date and get below result

```
 date                            Ids
----------------------------------------
2014-06-11 08:35:00.000          1,2
2014-06-11 08:50:00.000          3
2014-06-11 08:55:00.000          4,5
```

for that I have wrote a query

```
SELECT dateadd(millisecond, - datepart(millisecond, EventDate) ,EventDate), COUNT(*),
STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(MetricEventId as varchar) FROM MetricEvents ME1  WHERE ME1.MetricEventId = ME.MetricEventId FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') FROM MetricEvents ME
GROUP BY dateadd(millisecond, - datepart(millisecond, EventDate) ,EventDate),EventUrl
```

but I am getting error message saying

```
Column 'MetricEvents.MetricEventId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I know it wants me to group my query by MetricEvents.MetricEventId as well but that's not my requirement as I want to group them only by date, how can I get my grouped data in my sub query something like`ME1.MetricEventId IN (GROUPED IDS)` or is there any alternative

Comment: do you also required MetricEventId anywhere in your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.Date , (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+ cast(t2.id as nvarchar(5))
              FROM DemoTable t2 WHERE t2.Date = t1.Date
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) as IDS
FROM DemoTable t1
GROUP By t1.Date
```

Depending on if you have milliseconds in your data, you can also subtract the milliseconds as in your own SQL query.

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ae4e/31)

Comment: +1 for Fiddle Demo, I thought about it that way but I had other confusions on my mind, its very much clear now